# Custom legend not always rendering with react-chartjs-2

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs

I've made a custom legend using the `legendCallback` option on the Doughnut chart, but the legend doesn't always render.  However, on refreshing the page, the legend does render.  This leads me to believe that it's a problem with the component lifecycle, but I haven't been able to solve it with any use of React hooks.  I think the problem might be this: I'm giving the `<Doughnut>` component a refHook, and I can only call the `generateLegend()` function after the ref is present in the DOM, so maybe sometimes it doesn't make it before page render?  I really don't know.  I can't use `useEffect` because I would need to pass it the ref as a dependency and the component won't re-render when a ref changes.  Here is the component relevant component:

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'
import { Doughnut } from "react-chartjs-2";
import generateColors from 'utils/colorGen';
import parse from 'html-react-parser';

export const Donut = ({labelName, dataName, data}: DonutProps<CategoryTotalsObj>) => {

  let labels = data.map(e => e[labelName])
  let dataSet = data.map(e => Number(e[dataName].replace(/[^0-9.-]+/g,"")))
  const chartEl = useRef<Doughnut>(null)
  const colors = generateColors(data.length)
  
  const chart = {...}

  const options = {...}
  
  return (
    <div className='chart-wrapper' style={{width: '400px'}}>
      <Doughnut data={chart} options={options} ref={chartEl}/>
      {chartEl.current && parse(chartEl.current.chartInstance.generateLegend())}
    </div>
  )
}
```